# Dynamodb: Index on List attribute and query NOT_CONTAINS

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to figure out (at this point I think the answer is No) if it is possible to build a index on a List Attribute and query NOT_CONTAINS  on that attribute.

```
Example table:
Tasks

Task_id: string

solved_by: List<String> # stores list of user_ids who previously solved  this task.
```

My query would be:
Get me all the tasks not yet solved by current_user

```
select * from tasks where tasks.solved_by NOT_CONTAINS current_user_id
```

Is it possible to do this without full scans. I tried creating an attribute of type `L` but aws cli errors out saying `Member must satisfy enum value set: [B, N, S]`

If this is not possible with dynamodb, please suggest what datastore I can use.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your original question, you defined your access pattern as

> Get me all the tasks not yet solved by current_user

In a later comment, you clarified that the access pattern is

> A solver should be shown a task that is not yet solved by them.

which is a *slightly* different access pattern.

Here's one way you could fetch a task not yet solved by a user.

[image]

In this data model, I chose to model Users and Tasks as separate items.  Tasks have numerically increasing ID's.  Each User item should start with the `lastSolved` attribute set to 1.  Each time you fetch a new Task for a user, you fetch TASK#{last_solved+1} and increment the `lastSolved` attribute by 1.

You could probably take a similar approach by using timestamps instead of numbers... anything sortable, really.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, and as the error you got suggests, this is NOT possible.

However, I'd argue if your design couldn't be improved. Storing a potentially unbound list of entries (users in your case) inside a single item, which is limited to 400kb seems dangerous.

If instead, you'd store for each task the information that a particular user resolved it as a separate item (partition key - task_id, sort key - user_id) than you could easily look up if a user solved a task or not. You could also store additional information about the particular solution or attempts.

If you haven't heard of DynamoDB single table design yet, or how to overload indexes, I can recommend looking at

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-overloading.html
- https://www.dynamodbbook.com/

---

**Update**

I just realised, you care about a negation (NOT_CONTAINS) - for those, you can't use an index anyway. For the sort key you can only use positive comparison (=, <, >, <=, >=, between, begins_with): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions

So you might have to rethink the whole approach, to better pre-process the data stored in DDB, so it's easier to fetch, or pick a different database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.


solved_by is not unbounded. It is usually limited to 3 to 5 users. 


More information about the case. A task can be solved by 3 solvers.

A solver should be shown a task that is not yet solved by them.

Think of it like uber / doordash. Solver wants to know available tasks and solve them if possible.

Comment: right, if you want to use DDB to get top 5 tasks suggested for a particular user, then you would have to store those top 5 tasks in DDB by the user_id. Out of the top of my head I can't think of a straight forward way of building it otherwise, without using a scan. (I updated my answer to reflect this information)